# What would cause Content Porter to show expired license message

Tags: content-porter-2009, licensing

I have Content Porter SP2 running on Tridion 2011 SP1. When I try to connect to my instance of tridion to do an export, I get the message

> Licensing error, your license has expired

I checked `Tridion\licenses\content porter\cp_license.xml`

It shows the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <key-list>
    <key id="Gfb4Gca7GOyna/G4_*_2_2_[customer]_Content Porter_1375984195935" creation-date="2013-08-08" product="Content Porter" customer="[customer]" license-model="server" license-type="server_cpu_count" usage-limit="12" options="Version=2.1;ProductName=Content Porter">
    [license]
  </key>
</key-list>
```

I see the creation date as 2013-8-8. Is there any reason why I should be getting an expired license so soon?

Comment: seems like you copied the license file to the wrong location.. It should be under "Tridion/Content Porter/bin/cp_license.xml" but your license file is under "Tridion\licenses\content porter\cp_license.xml"

Comment: You should post that as an answer, Ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your cp_license.xml file should be located in the following folder:

> {Tridion-Home}/Content Porter/bin

You currently have it in

> Tridion/licenses/content porter